# Bind to ready event and another event with one anonymous function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, anonymous-function, ready

Normally to bind multiple events to an element, one would use `.on()`:

```
$("select#id").on("click change").function(){
    // do actions
});
```

However, the use of `ready` with `.on()` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8:

```
// Deprecated
$(document).on("ready", handler)
```

`.on("ready")` also behaves differently from `.ready()`.  Specifically, handlers will not execute if `.on("ready")` is bound to elements after they are ready, whereas `.ready()` will execute even when called after the elements are ready.

You could accomplish it with a named function:

```
var myFunction = function(){
    // do actions
};

$(document).ready(myFunction);
$("select#id").change(myFunction);
```

but that is less than ideal.  Using a single anonymous function would be cleaner.

Comment: `$("select#id").ready` makes no sense. `.ready` literally ignores whatever is inside of `$()`

Comment: In addition to @KevinB, `.ready`: "_Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded._" `$("whatever")` will not find any elements if the DOM is not ready when it's called.

Comment: It was meant to demonstrate the concept of binding to an element like you can do with `.on()`.  In any case I've changed it to use `$(document).ready()`.

Answer (score 0):

One method is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select#id").change(function(){
        // do actions
    }).change();
});
```

This will define the handler for the `change` event and then immediately call the `change` event.  Because it's inside of the `ready()` handler, it will be executed for both `ready` and `change` events.

Comment: immediately, if the `document` is already ready. Else, it will wait for the `document` to be ready. Note i said `document`, not the select element, because `.ready` does not wait for the element selected to be ready, it only looks at the `document`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you simply can't do it in more recent versions of jquery.

Your code as-is doesn't really make any sense, there's no reason to ever use anything other than `document` inside of `$()` when you're using `.ready` because `.ready` will simply ignore whatever is currently selected and perform it's action as if `document` were selected.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#theid").change(changeHandler).change();
});
```

If the only goal is to only use 1 anonymous function, event delegation will do it, however it's probably overkill.

```
$(document).on('change','#theid',thehandler);
```

where thehandler is an anonymous function or a named function, you choose.

Comment: This uses a named function, not an anonymous function as requested in the question.  And other than that this answer is identical to the one already posted.

Comment: It wasn't identical when i posted it. you edited the other answer 4 minutes later. whether or not the function is anonymous is irrelevant, you can place one in place of changeHandler without changing anything. Not to mention, changeHandler very well could be a reference to an anonymous function, such as in your last code snippet on your question.